# Can't compile for different java version

Tags: maven, compilation, version, java-7

I have a multimodule maven project. I do a `mvn clean install` of one of its examples which downloads and installs some dependencies.

if I do a `$ file WhateverClass.class` in certain jars from my WEB-INF/lib downloaded and compiled by Maven I keep getting

```
WhateverClass.class: compiled Java class data, version 51.0
```

which means that class has been compiled with Java 7.

I get this no matter how many times I compile that module by itself first! Why?
I have also checked the .class files from the modules themselves, after I see how the target folder has just been generated.

Along the project, some of the `POM.xml` specify a

```
<configuration>
  <source>1.5</source>
  <target>1.5</target>
</configuration>
```

but there are none specifying a higher java version.

My java version is:

```
java version "1.6.0_23"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11pre) (6b23~pre11-0ubuntu1.11.10)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode, sharing)
```

and javac version:

```
javac 1.6.0_23
```

**EDIT**

Here is my [effective-pom](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1Lg8GzZGJyLekVvbGVFWTM1M0E/edit)

Answer (score 0):

When you have problems like that, try to isolate the problem. The first step is to follow the path of the JAR backwards: Where did you find the class? Where did that JAR come from? If it came from a WAR, where did that come from? Do this until you find the computer on which the `.class` file is compiled. Check the JAR and the `.class` files in the `target/classes/` folder.

At each step, run `file` on `WhateverClass.class` and go one step further when you see Java 7.

When you have find the build computer, you can use the following options to debug the build process:

- `mvn -v` shows you the version of Maven and Java.
- `mvn help:effective-pom` shows the resolved POM (i.e. after including every parent POM, resolving all properties, you name it). Which `target` option is active?
- Run `mvn` with `-X` to get debug output. This can help to see which options Maven passes to forked processes.

Comment: thx @Aaron, I'm not sure what to do. When I do mvn -v I still get the Java6 version. And when looking at the effective-pom (EDIT) I see no trace of target 1.7. Not sure what you mean by "what computer jars came from".

Comment: Well, if you have a file on disk, that file came from somewhere. Hard disks don't suddenly spawn new files. So you need to find out where a file came from, then go there and repeat.